# Help identifying a post-apocalyptic movie with a monster

Tags: science-fiction, identify-this-movie

The movie must be from the 80's maybe early 90's. All I can remember is that it is about a group of people (women and men, young as far as I can remember) wandering through a desert in some kind of post-apocaliptic scenario. One of the girls from the group is trapped inside a cave (chained?) on a rock and raped by a monster (mutant?). The rest of the group finds some kind of scientific-research base and they are killed one by one by the offspring of the girl and the mutant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [The Terror Within](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terror_Within), (1989)?

> In a post-apocalyptic future, human survivors are fighting a group of
>   mutant monsters they refer to as "Gargoyles". Two of these survivors
>   Michael and John are out surveying the world after a chemical or
>   biological attack which left a large portion of the population mutated
>   or dead. The survivors are part of the Mojave Lab and have lost
>   contact with their sister Rocky Mountain Lab. Over the radio Sue and
>   David hear John and Michael fall under attack from the gargoyles while
>   investigating a large group of buzzards. In order to find John and
>   Michael, David and Linda go out of the bunker but find John and
>   Michael dead. They also find a live girl named Karen who they bring
>   back to their bunker. While under anesthesia Karen gives birth to a
>   gargoyle which gets loose in the bunker.
>
> ...
>
> These creatures reproduce quickly by raping human women and
>   impregnating them. The gestation period is short and deadly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like [Humongous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humongous)
No raping monster though.

Comment: It looks good, but no. The movie was a bit more "recent" maybe early 90's and there were no houses, just plain desert and some kind of lab/base. But thank you anyway